# Will Rosh Chodesh be observed in Heaven as per Isaiah 66:22-23?

Tags: isaiah, heaven

Isaiah 66:22-23 (NIV) reads:

> 22 “As the **new heavens and the new earth** that I make will endure before me,” declares the Lord, “so will your name and descendants endure. 23 **From one New Moon to another** and from one Sabbath to another, all mankind will come and bow down before me,” says the Lord.

Is a valid interpretation from the text that [Rosh Chodesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Chodesh) will be observed in Heaven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And the city had **no need of the sun, neither of the moon, to shine in it**: for the glory of God did lighten it, and the Lamb is the light thereof. [Revelation 21:23 KJV]

> And sware by him that liveth for ever and ever, who created heaven, and the things that therein are, and the earth, and the things that therein are, and the sea, and the things which are therein, **that there should be time no longer**: [Revelation 10:6 KJV]

Since there will no longer be any sun or moon (they are no longer required) and since there is no longer any time, I do not see how it would be possible to celebrate a monthly, repetitive festival.

And since the fulfillment of all of the types and figures and allegories will have been fulfilled, what on earth would be the point of remembering the **signification** of the reality when the reality has been fulfilled ?

The prophecy holds good while time endures. And the prophecy is fulfilled during time. But when all prophecies have been fulfilled, then time will cease.

Comment: Good points. So is Isaiah using new moons and sabbaths as a rhetorical way of saying "each month, each week" (i.e. always)?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator The prophecy is fulfilled by the New Testament, so the prophecy is fulfilled whilst time continues through the Church Age (now). Then time shall cease. (Not my down vote or vote to close, as yet.)

Comment: Ok, but then how do you exactly interpret "From one New Moon to another and from one Sabbath to another"? What was the intended meaning of that expression?

Comment: It applies as long as moons and sabbaths continue.

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on several fallacies which I will now dispel.

1. "New Moon" was never a mandated festival in the Torah or anywhere else.  There are references to it as a custom of the Jews at times (eg, Ps 81:3 [and full moon], 1 Sam 20:5, 18, 24, Amos 8:5, Eze 46:6, Hos 5:7, etc).  As further evidence of this, note the clear distinction between "new moon" festival vs the "appointed sacred festivals", presumably as listed in Lev 23.
2. The passage in Isa 66 is NOT discussing heaven nor the new earth.  It discussing a future state of Israel following the predicted Babylonian captivity that never eventuated because of other problems in Israel.  One can see this readily because of the references to (a) levites and priests (V21) and (b) dead corpses scattered over the ground (V24), etc.  [Now, some will interpret this passage as saying something metaphorically about heaven, that is another matter, but that is not the primary purpose of this prophecy.]
3. The passage is very terrestrial in its language and accords with Rev 20 about which predicts the New Jerusalem to be on earth.  This confirms that the passage cannot be about heaven.
4. In heaven, by definition, we are not on earth and thus, there can be no moon, and so can be no "new moon".  This also ignores the explicit statement in Rev 21:23 that there is no need of moonlight.

So what does the phrase, "From one New Moon to another and from one Sabbath to another" mean?  I believe it is Hebrew idiom for something like, "from month to month and week to week".  That is, the idea is simply on some kind of continual basis, people would come to worship God.

There is an oblique allusion to this in Rev 4:8-11 where (in heaven) God is worshiped constantly or continually.

Therefore, Isa 66 says nothing about what festivals, whether annual, monthly or weekly, might be celebrated by the redeemed either in heaven or the earth made new.  All it says is that God will be worshiped constantly.

Comment: What about Numbers 10:10 (NIV): "Also at your times of rejoicing—your appointed festivals and **New Moon** feasts—you are to sound the trumpets over your burnt offerings and fellowship offerings, and they will be a memorial for you before your God. **I am the Lord your God**." ?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator - note the same distinction as in Ezra 3:5 and Isa 1:14, Num 10:10 all say "new moon sacrifices AND the sacrifices for the appointed sacred festivals" - there is a distinction between what is appointed (as per Lev 23) and the cultural festivals such as new Moons, Purim, etc, which do not appear as appointed in the Torah.

Comment: I suggest you read Numbers 28:11-14.

Comment: @user21676 - thanks for this.  Such instructions do not constitute a festival (although that is what they later became, Amos 8:5), etc) but there was no suspension of regular work, no general gathering prescribed, etc.  These monthly offerings were simply done at the sanctuary, observed and performed by priests, but seen by few others as all regular work continued.  Places like Num 10:10, Isa 1:14, 1 Chron 23:31, there is a clear distinction between new moon vs appointed feasts of Lev 23.